# Solving an equality for a variable (involving trigonometry)

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification, approximation

Well, I have the equality:

$$\theta+2\epsilon\sin\left(\theta\right)+\frac{3}{2}\cdot\epsilon^2\cdot\left(\theta+\cos\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\approx\alpha\cdot\text{n}\tag1$$

> How can I solve this equation for $\theta$? For all the variables is know that they are real and positive.

---

**Background of the problem:**

I need to solve this for $\theta$:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

Now, for the LHS I got:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{\text{A}}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}\cdot\text{n}=\alpha\cdot\text{n}\tag3$$

Now, for the RHS:

$$\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\int_0^\theta\cos^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\color{red}{\approx}$$
$$\sum_{\text{k}=0}^2\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\int_0^\theta\cos^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=\theta+2\epsilon\sin\left(\theta\right)+\frac{3}{2}\cdot\epsilon^2\cdot\left(\theta+\cos\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)\tag4$$

Where $0<\theta<2\pi$, so the error (in the red approximation sign) is:

$$0<\text{E}_3=\left|\sum_{\text{k}=3}^\infty\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\theta\right|<\frac{2\pi\epsilon^3\left(4-3\epsilon\right)}{\left(\epsilon-1\right)^2}\tag5$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that is a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), which can therefore not be solved analytically.

Comment: Ah, then you might want to include that in your question (including the appropriate tags). Do standard approximate methods fail (like Mathematica's FindRoots or NSolve)? Or are you interested in for instance how many solutions there are?

Comment: Did the problem explicitly tell you to Taylor expand and throw away $O(n^3)$? Because it looks like the first three terms of a series..

Comment: Could you please include the original function as well as the whole series? Or just include the problem as a whole?

Comment: Thanks, will report back if I find something!

Comment: Two things: 1) Can $\epsilon$ be regarded as an infinitesimal (which in physics means $\epsilon\ll1$)? 2) Is $\theta$ an angle in a pendulum (or something similar), for which it can be assumed that $\theta$ is small (like $\theta<\pi/4$)?

Comment: @Lovsovs No!!!!!, we can say that $0<\epsilon<1$ but it is not that small! And for the angle we can also not say that, the only thing we can set is $0<\theta<2\pi$

Comment: Hmm, then I can't help. If those things were fulfilled, you could throw away the second-order term and say $\sin(\theta)\approx \theta$, when the problem becomes trivial (you get $\frac{2 \pi n}{A(1+2\epsilon)}=\theta$). If I know physics-problems (I am a physicist), this could very well be the case (we are crude people!)..

Comment: Okay, but keep in mind that it might not be possible to avoid those approximations if you want something analytical. Perhaps ask the original physical problem over on Physics.SE, with your attempt (as shown here).. They should know which approximations are appropriate. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=y(\theta)
$$

The inverse of this function reads
$$
\begin{aligned}
\theta(y)&=y\\
&+2 \sin (y)\epsilon\\
&+\frac12\left(5 \sin (y) \cos (y)-3 y\right)\epsilon^2\\
&+\frac{1}{12} (-3 \sin (y)+13 \sin (3 y)-36 y \cos (y))\epsilon^3\\
&+\frac{1}{96} (36 y-44 \sin (2 y)+103 \sin (4 y)-360 y \cos (2 y))\epsilon^4+\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

---

To derive the form of the coefficients, you need to use the identity
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{g(z)} f(x) \mathrm dx&=\int_0^{g(0)} f(x) \mathrm dx\\
&+z f(g(0))g'(0)\\
&+\frac12z^2\left(g'(0)^2f'(g(0))+f(g(0))g''(0)\right)\\
&+\frac16z^3\left(g'(0)^3f''(g(0))+3g'(0)g''(0)f'(g(0))+g'''(0)f(g(0))\right)+\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$
as given by Leibniz' formula. The general term is hopefully obvious from these first few terms.

---

In your particular case, $z\to\epsilon$, $g\to\theta$, and
$$
y\equiv\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\frac{2 \pi }{\left(1-\epsilon ^2\right)^{3/2}}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the closed frm of the infinite sum? Where did you get those terms from?

Comment: @JanEerland there is no closed form as far as I know. I just wrote $\theta=\theta_0+\theta_1\epsilon+\theta_2\epsilon^2+\cdots$, expanded the integrals in powers of $\epsilon$, and matched up powers of $\epsilon$ in both sides. This way you can determine the $\theta_i$'s to any desired order.

Comment: How did you expand it? I do not see where you get those terms from...