# Equation with integrals and absolute complex log function problem (physics related)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals, logarithms

I was working on a problem that I described in [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183262/solving-an-equality-for-a-variable-involving-trigonometry). The problem is the following: I need to solve this for $\theta$:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, for the LHS:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}\tag2$$

And the RHS:

$$\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2-1}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta\right)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\epsilon^2-1\right)^3}}\cdot\ln\left|\frac{1+\frac{\epsilon-1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-1}}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{1-\frac{\epsilon-1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-1}}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right|\tag3$$

Now, in the problem I have a value for $\epsilon$ that gives:

$$\epsilon^2-1<0\tag4$$

So, the value between the absolute value become a complex number and that results into:

$$\ln\left|\frac{1+\frac{\epsilon-1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-1}}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{1-\frac{\epsilon-1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-1}}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right|=0\tag5$$

So, we get the equality:

$$\frac{\text{n}}{\text{A}}\cdot\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2-1}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta\right)}\tag6$$

But the known variables are: $\epsilon\approx0.0167086$ and $\text{A}\approx365.25636$ and for $1\le\text{n}\le\text{A}$

> But this gives a complex solution for $\theta$ and that is not a possible solution for my problem, so where am I wrong?

Comment: You probably did a substitution in (3) disregarding the domain of the mapping function. In physics it usually works, but you found a case out of the usual. I can't find what's the other form you can use to express the ratio of tangents in the log, but you should find another expression for that term.

Comment: @N74 I checked the solution to $\left(3\right)$ with WolframAlpha and it gave me the same. And what is the way to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Wolfram](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%201%2F%281%2Ba%20cost%29%5E2&x=11&y=6) : 
$$\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2-1}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta\right)}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(\epsilon^2-1\right)^3}}\cdot\tanh^{-1}\left({\frac{\epsilon-1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2-1}}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right)\tag3$$Now, to avoid complex values, recall that $$ i \tanh^{-1} x=\tan^{-1} ix$$ so:
$$\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2-1}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{1+\epsilon\cos\left(\theta\right)}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\left(1-\epsilon^2\right)^3}}\cdot\tan^{-1}\left({\frac{1-\epsilon}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\right)$$
If I made no mistake, now all the values are real and you can find your angle.

Comment: It is definitly not try for every value of $\theta$

Comment: Please elaborate your comment.

Comment: Well, I think that you're right about your statement about my wrong evalution of the integral but the integral you stated in this answer is not true for every value of $\theta$. With other words can you prove that your integral after your word "so:" is true?

Comment: I just used a known relation between trigonometric and hyperbolic inverse functions. It is not maybe the right solution, but it is it's "analytic continuation"

Comment: and under the 2 your have switched: $\epsilon^2-1$ to $1-\epsilon^2$

Comment: I did it as $i=-{1 \over i}$